# Tkinter OptionMenu cannot open a second time using space

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having some trouble working around what I can only assume is a bug in Tkinter.

```py
from tkinter import *

def refocus(event, obj):
    obj.focus()

root = Tk()
options = ["Hello", "world", "How", "are", "you"]
v1 = StringVar()
v2 = StringVar()
v3 = StringVar()

o1 = OptionMenu(root, v1, *options)
o1.configure(takefocus=1)
o2 = OptionMenu(root, v2, *options)
o2.configure(takefocus=1)
o3 = OptionMenu(root, v3, *options)
o3.configure(takefocus=1)

o1.bind("<Configure>", lambda e=Event(), o=o1: refocus(e, o))
o2.bind("<Configure>", lambda e=Event(), o=o2: refocus(e, o))
o3.bind("<Configure>", lambda e=Event(), o=o3: refocus(e, o))

o1.pack(side=TOP)
o2.pack(side=TOP)
o3.pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

From the code there are 3 OptionMenus which I am trying to navigate using tab, space, arrows and Enter keys on the keyboard.

The issue is as soon as a menu box pops up it seems to loose focus of the original Option menu. To fix this I have bound configure which re-focuses the option box that it was on, but this only works if the input has changed so I need a new method of doing this.

Still there is an issue where if I select the wrong option, i have to cycle through all the other inputs (OptionMenus, Entrys, Checkboxes etc.) to get back to that option for it to open again.

In cases where there is only 1 OptionMenu then it will not work until I click another input with a mouse

I am looking for a way that I can focus back on the OptionMenu after the menu part has lost focus.

I have also tried using `o1['menu'].bind(...` but this did not work at all.

example process: `o1 focused -> pressed space -> open menu -> arrows to move -> enter to select -> focus on o1 -> press space -> open menu -> arrows to move -> enter to select -> focus on o1 -> press tab -> o2 focused`

Comment: Have you considered using at `ttk.Combobox` instead of an `OptionMenu`?

Comment: @BryanOakley No i was hoping to re-use as many Tk Widgets before moving onto ttk widgets.

Comment: Can I ask why you're avoiding ttk widgets?

Comment: I can't find a workaround for you, but I did notice that you can refactor `o1.bind("<Configure>", lambda e=Event(), o=o1: refocus(e, o)` to `o1.bind("<Configure>", refocus)` and `def refocus(event):` `event.widget.focus()` (food for thought)

Comment: @JRiggles Tk widgets dont require Style() but ttk widgets do. I am planning on adding ttk widgets with a theme/style manager but im not at that point yet. As my current code relies on tk.pallet() i would need to convert that into a ttk style and thats a lot of effort for 1 widget at the moment.

Comment: The focus always set  to o3. not even o1 or o2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def open_option_menu(event):
    # Get the widget from the event that tkinter passed in
    obj = event.widget
    # Calculate the x/y position of the popup window
    x = obj.winfo_rootx()
    y = obj.winfo_rooty() + obj.winfo_height()
    # Show the popup window
    #   obj["menu"] returns a `tk.Menu` object which has a `.post` method
    obj["menu"].post(x, y)
    # Stop tkinter from showing the popup window again.
    return "break"


root = tk.Tk()
options = ["Hello", "world", "How", "are", "you"]

v1 = tk.StringVar(root)
v2 = tk.StringVar(root)
v3 = tk.StringVar(root)

o1 = tk.OptionMenu(root, v1, *options)
o2 = tk.OptionMenu(root, v2, *options)
o3 = tk.OptionMenu(root, v3, *options)

o1.configure(takefocus=True)
o2.configure(takefocus=True)
o3.configure(takefocus=True)

o1.bind("<space>", open_option_menu)
o2.bind("<space>", open_option_menu)
o3.bind("<space>", open_option_menu)

o1.pack()
o2.pack()
o3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I think it's a bug in `tkinter` so I created a function `open_option_menu` that shows the popup window. If you don't like something about `tkinter`, you can rebuild it yourself with the functionality that you need. If you want to know more about the `.post` method, type `help(tkinter.Menu.post)` in `python`.

Note, this problem only exists on Windows, so the solution only works with Windows. On Ubuntu, the popup isn't focused when its shown.